# ORDER BY alternative values from main- and subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, postgresql-9.3

Right now I have a query that looks something like so:

```
SELECT id 
FROM post_table post
WHERE post.post_user_id = user_id
ORDER BY (SELECT max(comment_created_date) 
          FROM comments_table WHERE comments_post_id = post.id) DESC,
 post.post_created_date DESC
```

My idea for this query was that it would order a series of posts like so

```
Post 1:
    created Date: Jan 1 2015
    comments : []

Post 2:
     created Date: Jan 5 2015
     comments : []

Post 3:
     created Date : December 1 2014
     comments: [
         0: Created Date: Jan 6 2015
      ]
```

So in this case the order the posts would be returned in is

Post 3, Post 2, Post 1

Because Post 3 has a comment that is newer than any other posts, and Post 2 was created before Post 1.

But when I run the query, the posts are still all sorted by their created date and the query doesn't seem to take into account the comments created date.

Comment: Why post 2 was created before post 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work like this:

```
SELECT id 
FROM   post_table p
WHERE  post_user_id = $user_id  -- this is your input parameter
ORDER  BY GREATEST(
   (
   SELECT max(comment_created_date) 
   FROM   comments_table
   WHERE  comments_post_id = p.id
   )
 , post_created_date) DESC NULLS LAST;
```

You will want to add `NULLS LAST` if date columns can be NULL.

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)

If comments can only be later than posts (would make sense), you can use [`COALESCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) instead of [`GREATEST`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST).

Cleaner alternative (may or may not be faster, depending on data distribution):

```
SELECT id 
FROM   post_table p
LEFT   JOIN  (
   SELECT comments_post_id AS id, max(comment_created_date) AS max_date
   FROM   comments_table
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) c USING (id)
WHERE  post_user_id = $user_id
ORDER  BY GREATEST(c.max_date, p.post_created_date) DESC NULLS LAST;
```

Since you have pg 9.3 you can also use a `LATERAL` join. Probably faster:

```
SELECT id 
FROM   post_table p
LEFT   JOIN  LATERAL (
   SELECT max(comment_created_date) AS max_date
   FROM   comments_table
   WHERE  comments_post_id = p.id
   GROUP  BY comments_post_id
   ) c ON TRUE
WHERE  post_user_id = $user_id
ORDER  BY GREATEST(c.max_date, p.post_created_date) DESC NULLS LAST;
```

Answer (score 0):

The other thing I would suggest, if this is going to be a heavily hit query, is to create a calculated column on the post_table of `'date_last_commented'`
and use a trigger to update that on any insert or update of the comments table.

Then you could run simple query of:

```
SELECT id 
FROM post_table post
WHERE post.post_user_id = user_id
ORDER BY post.date_last_commented DESC nulls last, post.post_created_date DESC
;
```